# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error near «,» in Java

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

The below is the query generate by a prepareStatement in Java:

```
insert into schema.table(cedula, actividad, mercado, venta_mensual, fortalezas, crecer,
 financiamiento, monto, patente, contador, regimen_tri, problemas, bn_servicios, cursos ) 
values ('val', 'GAM', 'GAM', '0', 'Calidad', 'Sí', 'Sí', '122', 'Sí', 'Sí', 'ddd', 'aaa','ccc', 'bbb'  )
```

The Java code is:

```
try {
    PreparedStatement pstmt = conexion.prepareStatement(query); 
    pstmt.setString(1, n.getCedula()); 
        //the rest of the sets of the statement continue here from 1 to 13
        pstmt.executeUpdate(); 
    conexion.createStatement().execute(query);
        return true
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); // This error 
    return false;
}
```

The query is executed int the try statement and insert the values properly in the DB,  BUT it also throws the below exception, at line 192: here 'val':

```
 org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: error de sintaxis en o cerca de «,»
 org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error near ',' java
```

The error trace relate to postgres is here:

```
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2102)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1835)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:500)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:374)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:366)
```

By the way, the table has a bigserial value and all the others values showed in the query. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post your Java code and the stacktrace.

Comment: And use query.setString for your parameters. Don't just put them into the SQL statement.

Comment: Yes, I m using it the query is the final result of the preparedStatement

Comment: Show the contents of that String `query`.

Comment: Why do you execute it twice? `pstmt.executeUpdate(); 
    conexion.createStatement().execute(query);`

Comment: Not related to your problem, but: if `venta_mensual` is a numeric column, then you shouldn't pass a string literal to it. `'0'` is a string, `0` is a number. The same goes for monto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the query contains string constant within the `values` clause, as you have shown in the question:

```
query = "insert into table(cedula, actividad, mercado) "
        + " values ('val', 'GAM', 'GAM' )";
```

then this part of code will work fine:

```
conexion.createStatement().execute(query);
```

however this part of code won't work:

```
pstmt.setString(1, n.getCedula()); 
//the rest of the sets of the statement continue here from 1 to 13
```

It will throw an `PSQLException: The column index is out of range: X, number of columns: 0`, because `PreparedStatement.setXXX` methods expect placeholders `?` in the SQL statement.
On the other hand, when the insert statement contains placeholders (I assume that your INSERT **does contain** placeholders, because you haven't got the above exception):

```
query = "insert into tabla(cedula, actividad, mercado) "
    + " values ( ?, ?, ? )";
```

then `pstmt.setString...` statements will work fine, however this statement:

```
   conexion.createStatement().execute(query);
```

will throw an exception: `PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error near ','`

If your intent is to execute the INSERT twice, the first one using placeholders, and the second one using string values, you must do it in this way:

```
query1 = "insert into tabla(cedula, actividad, mercado) "
        + " values ('val', 'GAM', 'GAM' )";
query2 = "insert into tabla(cedula, actividad, mercado) "
        + " values ( ? , ? , ? )";

PreparedStatement pstmt = conexion.prepareStatement(query2); 
pstmt.setString(1, n.getCedula()); 
  //the rest of the sets of the statement continue here from 1 to 13
pstmt.executeUpdate(); 

conexion.createStatement().execute(query1);
```

Comment: Thanks! I wasnt aware of the 2 execute statements, I want just 1 insert, so I just delete:   conexion.createStatement().execute(query);

Answer (score -1):

String sql="INSERT INTO travel values(Source,Destination,VehicleType,PhoneNo)"
+" VALUES ('Mysore','Chennai','l',94400000)";

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).